# How can I select a default dropdown option with a ternary condition?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

How can we use a *ternary condition* within the [selected] or [ngvalue] property of option in order to have a default selected option?
For ex:

```
<input type="text" name="time">
<select class="form-control">
   <option [selected]="{time > 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM'}">
</select>
```

This default option is dependent on the input typed. If the input typed in the field is above 12, then it should automatically select PM, else AM.

Comment: You'd have to bind `time` to the input. Did you try? What happened? You should explain what's not working in your question.

Comment: Yes, I tried to use event binding on the input, so it can keep track of the value change. But how can we link that value to drop down selected option?

Answer (score 0):

handle  time with Hook State.Like
const time =